# Tensorflow rebuild warning when running

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow through pip, it showed its downloaded and installed properly, but when I run code it shows to rebuild it with correct compiler flags.

```
This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) 
to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.


tf.Tensor(-1883.2466, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Above output is what I get as error when I'm running this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))
```

Is it a bug or anything, please help as I'm trying to learn deep learning

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is not an error. The tensorflow binary you have installed probably does not support all CPU instructions your machine supports. So If you are not building something very complex, it might not have any impact.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is not complaining that AVX is not enabled. It is just an informative message saying only for some ops, Intel's oneDNN would be used and AVX or AVX2 would be turned on.

Please add label "comp:mkl", as requested at https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-optimization-for-tensorflow-installation-guide.html